Cannot index into null array, but array is hard coded with values
I have been working on this code for a couple weeks now, and am currently upgrading it. I have a functioning version using the .NET.httpwebrequest function. However, I'm needing to do weekly downloads of 20+ files, so I'd like to do simultaneous downloads which is not possible with that function to my understanding.
The issue I'm having now is any time I call my array OR the commented out hash from inside the joblist script block, I get a null index error for each value in the array/hash. I have re-worked this part of the code so many times and I am finally admitting defeat and asking for help from those better at powershell than I.
Also, my URL's and filenames have been edited out for security reasons. I am able to do the downloads outside of the loop/scriptblock, so I know that portion is functioning correctly.
$Directory = Read-host "enter file path for downloads"
#link and outFileName list
$links = @(
'google.com','yahoo.com','bing.com'
)
$fileNames = @(
'example1.zip','example2.zip','example3.zip'
)

$jobList = @()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $links.Count-1; $i++) {
    $currentPath = "$Directory\($($fileNames[$i]))"
    $jobList += Start-ThreadJob -Name $currentFile -ScriptBlock {
            Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $($links[$i]) -OutFile $currentPath -Certificate $targetCert
        }
}
Write-Host "Downloads started..."
wait-job -Job $jobList

foreach ($job in $jobList){
    Receive-Job -Job $job
}

EDIT***
So I fixed the null index issue, but now the cert im using to access the website is getting the null issue??? this is weird.
$jobList = $fileUrlNamesHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $loopCert = $targetCert
    $currentPath = "$Directory\($_.value)"
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.key -OutFile "$Directory\($_.value)" -Certificate $loopCert
} -ThrottleLimit 20 -AsJob

$jobList | Wait-job | Receive-job

I tried duplicating the cert variable inside the loop, but it's erroring out as null on the second file. This first one works perfectly and prompts for a pin as it should.
